# Skype in C# (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: database, c#, skype, wpf

I am writing a Database system in C# and Visual Studio 2015 (`WPF`). I have a table of users that lists their names and their internal telephone numbers. There are two scenarios we would like to achieve, both being best-case;

1. A user is able to click on a phone number in the `DataGrid` and the
   dialing process is started in C#, which calls the Skype for Business
   program and dials the employee through Skype for Business.
2. The user clicks on the phone number in the `DataGrid`, and the call
   is automatically dialed out ausing a Mitel phone system, allowing the
   user to dial any employee our company they wish to contact from
   within the Database system itself.

I understand these are probably two completely different systems but currently we are stuck for either. I've tried using the `SKYPE4COM` API for `C#` but as far as I can see it is now deprecated and unusable.

Comment: Why not simply use the Skype protocol handler for `skype://` or `callto://`? I don't know Mitel, but does it support `sip://`?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Hi Thomas, thanks for your answer. I'm not sure what either of those are, could you point me in the direction of a tutorial?